# write a list in a cell csv python

Tags: python, list, csv

I have a list of strings to write in a field in CSV. I read this list in another program. However when I  read it back , it is read as a string and not list. Code so far

```
import csv  
import codecs
def write_csv(outputcsv, rows, fieldnames):
            try:
                        restval=""
                        extrasaction="ignore"
                        dialect="excel"
                        outputfile = codecs.open(outputcsv + ".csv",'w')
                        csv_writer = csv.DictWriter(outputfile, fieldnames, restval, extrasaction, dialect, quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONNUMERIC)
                        csv_writer.writeheader()
                        csv_writer.writerows(rows) 
                        outputfile.close()
            except csv.Error :
                            print "outputcsverror"


def read_csv(inputcsv):   
                try:
                    inputfile = codecs.open(inputcsv+ ".csv",'r') 
                    result = list(csv.DictReader(inputfile))
                    return result              
                except csv.Error:
                            print "inputcsverror" 





if __name__ == '__main__':
            rowdict=dict()
            Allrows=list()
            rowdict["stringlist"]=["Abc", "Def"]
            Allrows.append(rowdict)
            fieldnames=["stringlist"]
            outputcsv="teststrings"
            write_csv(outputcsv, Allrows, fieldnames)
            listRows=read_csv(outputcsv)
            print listRows[0]["stringlist"][0]
```

When I access listRows[0]["stringlist"], it returns a string.
The above print gives 
[
as compared to Abc

Answer (score 0):

Your ["Abc", "Def"] are in the same field under the name "stringlist". If you want the list result. Try

```
your_list = listRows[0]["stringlist"].split(',')
```

Comment: but I  can have , in my string field. My string field is a big text.

Comment: in this case, you need to use different columns for each item.

Comment: I did not want to use different columns since the number of entries in the stringlist varies and thought there might be some way to store and read back lists

Comment: There is no way to tell comma as seperator or text. You can either use for loop to auto generate column names or think of a special seperator.

Comment: would it be possible to write and read back dictionaries in a cell. newdict=dict()                newdict["1"]="Abc"                newdict["2"]="Def"                                                                                                  rowdict["stringlist"]=newdict                                                                    After writing the csv, when I read  stringlist again, would it be possible to read back a dictionary